# Getting numeric value out of offsetX value

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to solve an equation which involves an interaction of mouse click/touch action and movement. Works pretty much like a slider but it will make an animation run frame by frame, that's why I just need the numbers.

```
<html>
    <header>
        <!-- By the way, this is not the actual html file, just a generic example. -->
        <style>
            #box{
                border:1px solid red; 
                height:500px;
                width:500px;
            }
        </style>
    </header>
    <body>
        <div id="box" onclick="posInicial()" onmousemove="posMove()"></div>
        <div id="Z" ></div>

        <script>
            function posInicial() {
                var posX = event.offsetX;
                return posX;
            };

            function posMove() {
                var posY = event.offsetX;
                return posY;
            };

            var z = posY - posX;

            document.getElementById("Z").innerHTML =  z;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Whenever I write the code below I can get the numbers to show and update live in the HTML, but I need the actual values in the "minus" operation for the animation frame control

```
function posInicial() {
    var posX = event.offsetX;
    document.getElementById("Z").innerHTML = posX;
};
```

Can someone please save me?

Comment: You should be getting errors in your console with this code, since neither `posX` nor `posY` are defined when the line `var z = posY - posX;` is evaluated. Also, the value of `posX` from `posInicial` doesn't go anywhere except back to the DOM, which doesn't know what to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function won't work because you variables scopes are local.
Your `var posX` will be only accessible in `poInicial()`. An easy workaround is to make them global wich would be like this :

```
var posX;
var posY;

function posInicial() {
    posX = event.offsetX;
};

function posMove() {
    posY = event.offsetX;
};

var z = posY - posX;

document.getElementById("Z").innerHTML =  z;
```

But it won't work since you `document.getElementById("Z").innerHTML =  z;` will be only called on script load. You don't need to return somethings since your not using your functions to get a value but to set one.

```
// Global variables
var posX;
var posY;

function posInicial() {
    posX = event.offsetX;
    writePosition();
};

function posMove() {
    posY = event.offsetX;
    writePosition();
};

function writePosition() {
    var z = posY - posX; // Local since we just need the value to write in Z element.
    document.getElementById("Z").innerHTML =  z;
}
```

Here's a link to help you with scopes : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Answer (score 1):

Use `Number.parseInt`. Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseInt

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse an integer from a string, use [Number()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) or [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```
var str ="101";
var num = Number(str);
var int = parseInt(str);
```

Comment: [`event.offsetX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetX) is already a number...

Answer (score 0):

The values are already numbers, but you have several issues with your code. Mainly the calculation `posY - posX` is only executed once when the page is displayed. You need to put it in a function and then call it from the `posMove()` event:

```html
<html>
<header>
  <style>
    #box {
      border: 1px solid red;
      height: 500px;
      width: 500px;
    }
  </style>
</header>
<body>
  <div id="box" onclick="posInicial()" onmousemove="posMove()"></div>
  <div id="Z"></div>
  <script>
    var posX = 0;

    function posInicial() {
      posX = event.offsetX;
    };

    function posMove() {
      posDisplay(event.offsetX);
    };

    function posDisplay(posY) {
      var z = posY - posX;
      document.getElementById("Z").innerHTML = z;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dear Racil,

you're the bomb. I'm a designer, so I'm starting to explore this crazy world. Javascript is the easiest one, I know, but since I speak squares, circles and triangles, I`m having a hard time.